# How do you link GCM chrome push notifications and payload data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Push notifications in Chrome via GCM are driving me crazy.

I've got everything up and running. I serve the push using my python server to GCM. A service worker displays the push notification fine.

To my knowledge, there is NO data passed with push events. Sounds like it's coming soon but not available yet.

So just before the push notification shows, I call my server to get extra data for the push notification. But I have no information on the push notification to send to my server to match and return relevant data.

Everything I can think of to match a notification and user data is purely speculative. The closest thing I can find is a timestamp object on the PushEvent{} that roughly matches the successful return of the GCM call for each user.

So how are other people handling custom payload data to display Chrome push notifications?

The PushEvent{} does not seem to have any ID associated with it. I know the user that the push is for because I've previously stored that information at the time of registration.

But once I receive a push, I have no idea of knowing what the push was for.

I would like to avoid:

- Trying to match based on timestamp (since notifications displays are not guaranteed to be instant).
- Trying to pull the 'latest' data for a user because in my case, there could be several notifications that are sent for different bits of data around the same time.

How are other sites like Whatsapp and Facebook linking custom payload data with a seemingly sterile event data as a result of a push notification?

How are you doing it? Any suggestions?

Here's what my receiver code looks like:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

    event.waitUntil(
    fetch("https://oapi.co/o?f=getExtraPushData&uid=" + self.userID + "&t=" + self.userToken).then(function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
        throw new Error();  
      }

      return response.json().then(function(data) {  
        if (data.error || !data.notification) {  
          console.error('The API returned an error.', data.error);  
          throw new Error();  
        }  

        var title = data.notification.title;  
        var message = data.notification.message;  
        var icon = data.notification.icon;  

        return self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
          body: message,  
          icon: icon,  
        });  
      });  
    }).catch(function(err) {  
      console.error('Unable to retrieve data', err);

      var title = 'An error occurred';
      var message = 'We were unable to get the information for this push message';  
      var icon = "https://oapi.co/occurrences_secure/img/stepNotify_1.png";  
      var notificationTag = 'notification-error';  
      return self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
          body: message,  
          icon: icon,  
          tag: notificationTag  
        });  
    })  
);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem, and i've been fiddling with the same when i wanted to use chrome notification. You can use indexedDB to save ObjectStore and retrieve data in webServices.

IndexedDB is accessible to webservices. I am using it to store user information and when the user recieves a push notification i pass the stored access key to identify the user and pass him relevent information.
Here's matt gaunt's tutorial which says indexed db is accessible to web services: 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/

Here's a good indexedDB tutorial: 
http://blog.vanamco.com/indexeddb-fundamentals-plus-a-indexeddb-example-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. Imagine that a user might have 5 push notifications that all push at the same time and contain 5 unique messages for a particular user. When the service worker receives each push, I need to query my server to retrieve the details for each push. But since each of those 5 pushes do not contain any unique information, I'm not sure how to link one push with additional detail on my server. (Unless it's done in a very hacky way, storing lists of unread notifications on the server and pulling the oldest of the stack - for instance)

Comment: I think you just need to be a little tricky. In our case we are limiting the number of simultaneous notification to latest 3. When the user recieves this notification he does a call to our server with his uniqe user id and some other information which we saved in the indexedDB. Using this information we recognize the user and check our db for the message which this user should recieve and respond back. The web service then shows notification from the response which we gave.Thus you dont need to have uniqe info during the push but rather can retrieve them of server when worker recievs push notf

Comment: Yeah what we have now is very similar - it just seems very sloppy. A simple unique ID, generated at the time of the push on our server and sent along with the push would be enough to perfectly link the two. Seems like a safe and simple solution that should have been included from the beginning.

Comment: Great... May be in the next version service worker will be able to read the payload sent along with push notification. It seems they have plans for it. Do accept the answer if you think it is satisfactory.

Comment: Honestly I don't really think this is an answer to my question. We're simply discussing various hacks to make this work. For posterity, I'd rather have a more specific answer that will help others solve this problem.

Comment: Yup, thats why i asked to accept if its satisfactory. Presently however this is the way in which many people like pushcrew, roost and others are doing. We may have a better solution in future version.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are still in the past. That is, sending only a push trigger to your browser with no payload it's now time to move on with time. You can now send payload in your push events. Since you seem familiar with GCM, it's ok to go with that though there is now the Web Push Protocol which is browser vendor independent.

Briefly, to make that work you need to encrypt your payload with specifications found [here](https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push), in your server.

There is a `node` by google chrome and `PHP` implementations for that, that I know of.
You may check out the [PHP Web Push here](https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push).

In the browser you would need to provide the subscription object now with the `p256dh` and `auth` on top of the endpoint as before.

You may check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption) out for more details.